# How to handle multiple buttons enter key functionality?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my page there are two buttons. For enter key functionality I have written the following jQuery code.

```
$(function () {    
   $("#first-button-id").keyup(function (e) {
      if (e.keyCode == '13') {
         e.preventDefault();                  
      }
   }).focus();


   $("#second-button-id").keyup(function (e) {
      if (e.keyCode == '13') {              
         e.preventDefault();                 
      }
   }).focus();
});
```

But always when click on enter key first one is firing. Please tell me how to handle the multiple button enter key functionality.

Comment: The focus always remains on second button on DOM ready.

Comment: Only one input element can have the focus at any give time - and thus only one input element (the focused element) can get a keypress (be it <enter> or "A") event directly.

Comment: can you provide the html?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this 
**HTML :**

```
<label>TextBox : </label>
<input id="textbox" type="text" size="50" />
<label>TextBox 2: </label>
<input id="textbox2" type="text" size="50" />
```

**JQuery**

```
$('#textbox , #textbox2').keyup(function(event){

    var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
    if(keycode == '13'){
        alert('You pressed a "enter" key in textbox');  
    }
    event.preventDefault();
}).focus();
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AUZm4/1/)

Some browser prefer keycode and other use which ... I suggest you to use both..

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to focus on two buttons at the same time. Try doing something like this:

```
$("#button1").keypress(function(event){  
    if ( event.which == 13 ){     
       //Do something}

$("#button2").keypress(function(event){
    if( event.which == 13 ){
        //Do something else}
```

The problem i think is with your event.preventDefault() function which stops the propogation of the *event* once a function is executed. In your case, your first function might be getting completed before the second one and hence the second one gets aborted in the middle.

Comment: event.preventDefault() does not stop propagation.  It simply does what it says, prevents the default behavior of the event.  For instance if you clicked on an anchor tag <a href="...."> the default behavior is to change to the page in the href.  Calling event.preventDefault() would stop this behavior.

Comment: Propagation happens when a user clicks on one tag that is nested inside another.  For instance an anchor tag inside a table cell, <td><a href="...">...</a></td> the click first happens to the anchor tag, then there will also be a click for the table cell.  event.stopImmediatePropagation() and event.stopPropagation() both stop  the event from bubbling up the DOM tree.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the first submit button is always firing is because that's the default behavior of a web page which you haven't actually altered with your code.

Try this:

```
$(function () {    
   $("#first-button-id, #second-button-id").keyup(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopImmediatePropagation();
      if (e.keyCode == '13') {
         $(this).trigger("click");                 
      }
   });
});
```

What you seem to be asking about strikes me as rather odd.  It looks like you want second-button to be 'clicked' if the focus is on second-button and enter is pressed.  Tabbing until the focus is on the correct button is really the only practical way this could happen.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#first-button-id , #second-button-id ").keyup(function(event){ 
if ( event.which == 13 ) {
     alert("you pressed enter.");
     event.preventDefault(); 
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```js
$('#first-button-id').on("keydown", function (e) 
{
   if (e.keyCode == 13)
   {
       e.preventDefault();
       $("first-button-id").click();
   }
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may answer the question, it is better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers tend to be less useful in the long run. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for some more info.